# How to call Groovy script using Python?

Tags: python, groovy

I would like to know if there is a possibility to call a groovy script via Python?

I am using Groovy to export some data from a website and after this I am using Python to anaylse this data. I now would like to automate this process. Is there a way to do this?

What I did so far and what did not work out was this:

```
import os
os.system("path/to/groovy/script.groovy")
```

I did not get an error but a '0' was returned.

And the second trial was to use:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["groovy","path/to/groovy/script.groovy"])
```

Which returned an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: You can integrate Groovy and Jython quite well.

Comment: And if nothing else, fork a new process and read the result from stdout/err. Please add what you have tried and how it failed so we can improve on it.

Comment: Could it be, that your groovy installation is not in your path?

Comment: You are right. Thanks for your support!